# Parse pyspark array into columns using automated select statement

Tags: arrays, dataframe, parsing, pyspark

I want to parse my `pyspark` `array_col` dataframe into the columns in the list below. I have two dataframes: one schema dataframe with the column names I will use and one with the data formatted as rows of arrays.

i.e.

```
schema:
cols = ['Brand', 'Price', 'Sales', 'Timestamp']
```

df:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|array_col                                     |
+----------------------------------------------+
|["volvo", "$20K", "2", "12/6/2022 5:15:46 PM"]|
|["bmw", "$40K", "1", "11/6/2022 6:15:76 PM"]  |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

I can parse the array into their respective columns with the number of columns and column names hardcoded below, but I want to automate my script to create the `select` statement below so I can use this script for other dataframes without manually coding in the number of columns and column names.

```
newdf = df.select(df.array_col[0], df.array_col[1], df.array_col[2], df.array_col[3]).toDF(*['Brand', 'Price', 'Sales', 'Timestamp']).display()
```

I tried creating a string to use `f string` format to replace the statements, but the `df.select` statement isn't a string so this wouldn't work. Is there a way to automate these values or a better way to parse the array into the columns?

```
newdf_str = []
for i in range(len(cols)):
    newdf_str.append('newdf.array_col['+str(i)+']')
    newdf_str = ', '.join(newdf_str)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What does your `schema dataframe` look like? Because `cols = ['Brand', 'Price', 'Sales', Timestamp']` is a list, not a df. If your schema is stored in a list, then it will be more simple than in a df

Comment: Please check my answer to see if it works as your intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "*" to unpack element in a list like below

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import array
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Example").getOrCreate()

# Original list contain column names
cols = ['Brand', 'Price', 'Sales', 'Timestamp']

# Create the original dataframe with a single column named `array_col`
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (["volvo", "$20K", "2", "12/6/2022 5:15:46 PM"],),
    (["bmw", "$40K", "1", "11/6/2022 6:15:76 PM"],)],
    ["array_col"])
df.show(truncate=False)
# +--------------------------------------+
# |array_col                             |
# +--------------------------------------+
# |[volvo, $20K, 2, 12/6/2022 5:15:46 PM]|
# |[bmw, $40K, 1, 11/6/2022 6:15:76 PM]  |
# +--------------------------------------+

# Dynamically create DF from cols and df
newdf = df.select(*[col("array_col")[i].alias(cols[i]) for i in range(len(cols))])
newdf.show(truncate=False)
# +-----+-----+-----+--------------------+
# |Brand|Price|Sales|Timestamp           |
# +-----+-----+-----+--------------------+
# |volvo|$20K |2    |12/6/2022 5:15:46 PM|
# |bmw  |$40K |1    |11/6/2022 6:15:76 PM|
# +-----+-----+-----+--------------------+
```